# How to navigate from one component to other and hide first component?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular8

I want to Navigate from dashboard component to participant view component.  I can show participant view component but not sure how to hide the dashboard component.  Any help will be appreciated. I tried bunch of things but nothing seems to work.  I might have missed something that I couldn't figure out.

Below are my files:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ParticipantsViewComponent } from './components/ParticipantsView/participants-view/participants-view.component';
import { DashBoardComponent } from './components/DashBoardComponent/dash-board/dash-board.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "dash-board", component: DashBoardComponent },
  {path: "participantsView", component: ParticipantsViewComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**landingPage.html (index.html)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <risk-assessment-stage></risk-assessment-stage>
</body>
</html>
```

**app-landing.html**

```
<dash-board></dash-board>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<input type="button" value="clear" (click)="navigateToParticipantView()"/>
<a routerLink="/participantsView" routerLinkActive="active">
  Click here
</a>
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {Router,ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router"

@Component({
  selector: 'dash-board',
  templateUrl: './dash-board.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dash-board.component.scss']
})
export class DashBoardComponent {

  constructor(public router: Router){}

  navigateToParticipantView(){
    this.router.navigate(['/participantsView']);
  }

}
```

[image]

As you can see that I am able to see participant view component but I am not able to hide the button and link.  Please help.  Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it worked!!!!

All I had to change my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ParticipantsViewComponent } from './components/ParticipantsView/participants-view/participants-view.component';
import { DashBoardComponent } from './components/DashBoardComponent/dash-board/dash-board.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "dash-board", component: DashBoardComponent },
  {path: "participantsView", component: ParticipantsViewComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/dash-board', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app-landing.html

```
<dash-board></dash-board>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```